# Laravel 9 Validator Make Method Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-validation, laravel-request

I have written this code in the Controller as the Action of a form:

```
public function submitAsk(Request $request)
    {
        $rules = [
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|max:1000',
            'category' => 'required',
            'tags' => 'required',
        ];

        $messages = [
            'required' => ':attribute can not be empty'
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request, $rules, $messages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('questions/ask')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }

        ...
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Illuminate\Validation\Factory::make(): Argument #1 ($data) must be of type array, Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in C:\projectname\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 338

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manually-creating-validators doesn't help?

Comment: Well you are passing the `$request` directly instead of `$request->all()`

Comment: @brombeer I just copied and pasted the code from there so this means that it does not help

Comment: "_I just copied and pasted the code from there_" I bet you did not. Every example on that page uses `$request->all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You just have a simple syntax issue:**

You must pass `$request->all()` array not the `$request instance`

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
```

**Reference**: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manually-creating-validators